# Plone: The number of fields in the new order differs from the number of fields in the schema

Tags: python-2.7, widget, plone, plone-4.x

I have a **batch.py** file which have many fields in it. So i am Trying to add a new ReferenceField in batch.py as per my requirement.

```
ExtReferenceField('Asfield',
        required = 0,
        multiValued=1,
        allowed_types = ('AnalysisService',),
        referenceClass = HoldingReference,
        relationship = 'BatchAsfield',
        widget=SearchAnalysisWidget(
            label=_("AS Search"),
            description="",
            render_own_label=False,
            visible={'edit': 'visible', 'view': 'visible'},
            #visible=True,
            base_query={'inactive_state': 'active'},
            catalog_name='portal_catalog',
            showOn=True,
            colModel = [{'columnName':'AsCode','width':'20','label':_('Code')},
                        {'columnName':'AsName','width':'80','label':_('Name')},
                        {'columnName':'AsDate','width':'80','label':_('Date')},
                        {'columnName':'AsTat','width':'80','label':_('TAT')},
                        {'columnName':'AsLocation','width':'80','label':_('Location')},
                        ],
        ),
    ),
```

It gives me error like:

> ValueError: The number of fields in the new order differs from the
>   number of fields in the schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the Solution for this error. This error is coming because i am not added my **Asfield** in the **getOrder** method of **batch.py** file.

Actually our widgets needs a particular order to show at browser.So by using the **getOrder** method we can maintain the order of all widgets(fields) at browser. This getOrder is defined in same file **batch.py**.

```
def getOrder(self, schematas):
        schematas['default'] = ['id',
                                'title',
                                'description',
                                'BatchID',
                                'ClientPatientID',
                                'Patient',
                                'Client',
                                'Doctor',
                                'Asfield',
                                'ClientBatchID',
                                'ReceiptNo',
                                'AmountPaid',
                                'BatchDate',
                                'OnsetDate',
                                'PatientAgeAtCaseOnsetDate',

                                 ]
        return schematas
```

I just add **Asfield** (ReferenceField) after the Doctor (at the browser this Referencewidget will show just after Doctor). You can add your widget where you want it.

It is simple Solution for this value error.